# Extract string upto specific char in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, substr

I would like to extract the string just before the '@' symbol in SQL Server.

example:

```
abcdef@opkac
o/p - abcdef
```

Comment: I would like to know how to do similar way in netezza too. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
select left(str, charindex('@', str) - 1)
```

Note:  this will return an error if the character is not present.  So you might want:

```
select (case when str like '%@%' then left(str, charindex('@', str) - 1) end)
```

EDIT:

If you are using Netezza, you might need to use `substring()` instead of `left()`.  Postgres now supports `left()`, but didn't when Netezza started using it:

```
select (case when str like '%@%' then substring(str from 1 for charindex('@', str) - 1) end)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I get an error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'left'.